# Java Swing GUI layout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, layout-manager

I am building a simple Swing app that I want to have text fields/ combo boxes / dropdowns / etc. going down the page from left to right.  I also want to be able size the textfields and combo boxes to the size of the text and no bigger, like on a web page.

I have create a `JFrame`, which contains a list of panes.  Currently the Search pane has a lable on the right, then the textfield, and then a search button which all appear vertically the full length of the screen.

Here is the code:

```
public class SearchEvent {

public JPanel createSearchPane() {
    JTextField searchEvent = new JTextField();
    //searchEvent.setSize(10, 20);
    //searchEvent.setSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    GridLayout topLayout = new GridLayout(1,1);
    panel.setLayout(topLayout); 
    panel.add(new JLabel("Event  to search"));
    panel.add(searchEvent);
}
}

MainClass{

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Search Event ");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    tabbedPane.addTab("Search", null, new SearchEvent().createSearchPane(),"Search an event");
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

            //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

How can I make the text field appear on the right of the screen, the size of the text in the text field and the label to appear on the left beside the text field?

Comment: Read about what the [GridLayout constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout-int-int-) does.  You’re currently specifying a GridLayout with one row and one column.  (GridLayout is the wrong layout to use for this anyway;  read about the other layouts in [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/).)

Comment: So I had looked on this already, but I decided to try SpringLayout. Its the same issue that when the window resizes the fields become massive.  I don't want the textfields to become any bigger when the window is resized, the textfield is nevet going to be more than 20 characters or so, so I don't want a massive height for the field, or width when the window increases in size it just looks silly.  If I set maximium size on the textfield it didn't seem to work either as when I maximise the window the texffields disappear(labels stay the right size and in the correct place).

Comment: copied from here-> Followed from here-> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringGridProject/src/layout/SpringUtilities.java

Comment: SpringLayout is very hard to use;  it’s really meant for use by interactive GUI builder software.  If you intend to write complex user interfaces, you should learn GridBagLayout (which is not the same as GridLayout);  it is difficult to learn (because layouts in general are complex), but once you’ve learned how it works, it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using springLayout I achieved what I wanted to do by the following 2 lines:

textField.setMinimumsize(tf.getPreferredsize())
textField.setMaximumSize(tf.getPreferredSize())

For what i want to do im not sure its worth investing in the time to learn gridbaglayout